# eror in python unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, tkinter

I get this error in Python.

What should I do to fix the error?

My program is written with Tkinter

Thanks if you solve my problem

```
from tkinter import *    
def Diagnosis():        
    get1 =  inp.get()
    if get1 / 2 == '0':
        Label(windows,font = 'IranNastaliq',text = 'عدد زوج است').pack()
    else:
        Label(windows,font = 'IranNastaliq',text = 'عدد فرد است ').pack()
   
windows = Tk()
windows.geometry('500x600')
windows.configure(bg ='aqua')
windows.maxsize(500,600)
windows.minsize(400,500)

inp = Entry(windows,font ='IranNastaliq' )
inp.pack()

windows.title("icc-aria gui app")

btn = Button(windows)

btn.configure(text="تایید",font = ('IranNastaliq',14),command = Diagnosis )

btn.pack()

windows.mainloop()
```

Comment: Probably do `get1 = int(inp.get())` or `get1 = float(inp.get())`

Answer (score 1):

convert input to int or float:

```
from tkinter import *    
def Diagnosis():        
    get1 =  int(inp.get())
    if get1 / 2 == 0:
        Label(windows,font = 'IranNastaliq',text = 'عدد زوج است').pack()
    else:
        Label(windows,font = 'IranNastaliq',text = 'عدد فرد است ').pack()
   
windows = Tk()
windows.geometry('500x600')
windows.configure(bg ='aqua')
windows.maxsize(500,600)
windows.minsize(400,500)

inp = Entry(windows,font ='IranNastaliq' )
inp.pack()

windows.title("icc-aria gui app")

btn = Button(windows)

btn.configure(text="تایید",font = ('IranNastaliq',14),command = Diagnosis )

btn.pack()

windows.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

From your error message it sounds like `inp.get()` returns a string.

You can convert it to an int:

```py
def Diagnosis():        
    get1 =  inp.get()
    if int(get1) / 2 == 0:
        Label(windows,font = 'IranNastaliq',text = 'عدد زوج است').pack()
    else:
        Label(windows,font = 'IranNastaliq',text = 'عدد فرد است ').pack()
```